# How to solve "Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']" build error?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am developing an android application.It was working before.My app started to give "build failed". Related failure log is as follows.What problem can cause this problem.I cleaned and run make app but it didn't solve it.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Software\workspace\WaterMeterReader\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Could not create an instance of type  com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated.

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --     debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

my build.gradle file i as follows as well.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.belsoft.watermeterreader"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

    dependencies {
      compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
      compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
      compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.3.0'
      compile files('libs/Sewoo_Android_1070.jar')
  }
```

Comment: have you upgraded your studio or gradle ?

Comment: No I havent upgrade my studio and gradle